# Open differents pages ionic 3 with push notifications

Tags: push-notification, ionic3

I need help, 
I am trying to open different pages of my application in ionic3, I can do it for a specific page, but I want to differentiate the type of notification, example if the notification is of the message type, my message page is opened and if it is another type of notification will open a different page.

```
    pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => {
        this.nav.push(PushNotification); //here open specific page, but I need to open not only a specific page but several pages.
        if (notification.additionalData.foreground) {
            let youralert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                title: 'New Push notification',
                message: notification.message,
            });
            youralert.present();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey Lenin so normally you are the one defining push notification object and you can add properties to it. What is your case? do you control PushNotification object properties? if so can you share whats in it today?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I do not know how to validate what type of notification I received, The example is I have two different processes, one of which I have already implemented and that process opens the messaging page, and the other process that sends push notifications in the application differentiate and open another page, Can I do that?

Comment: Can you console log you notification object?